# Matching element of arrays on a condition

Tags: c, arrays

if node[i] and node[i+1] are present in the neighbor[i], then store the 'i' position of node and print the 'i' value of node.

this is also done by reversing the node array(only) and same type of check and print is done with the neighbor[i].

This code is written by me and works well, is there any other efficient method to perform this.

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main()
{
    int node[5] = {44,5,4,6,40};
    int neighbor[4]= {40,3,4,6};
    int i=0,j=0,k=0;
    int found_indices[5]; // array used to store indices of found entries..
    int count = 0; //n entries found;
    int fwd_count=0;
    int postn;
    int find;
    // to find in forward direction
     for (i=0; i<4; i++) {
        for (j=0; j<4; j++) {
            if (node[i]==neighbor[j]) {
                postn=node[i];
                for (k=0; k<4; k++) {
                    if (node[i+1]==neighbor[k]) {
                      found_indices[fwd_count ++] = postn; // storing the index of found entry


                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }

   if (fwd_count!=0) {  
       for (i=0; i<fwd_count; i++)
           printf("forward relay for ==%d\n", found_indices[i]);

   } else{
     printf("Relay not found in forward\n");
  }



 // to find in backward direction
    for (i=4; i>0; i--) {
        for (j=0; j<4; j++) {
            if (node[i]==neighbor[j]) {
                postn=node[i];
                for (k=0; k<4; k++) {
                    if (node[i-1]==neighbor[k]) {
                      found_indices[count ++] = postn; // storing the index of found entry


                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }

   if (count!=0) {  
       for (i=0; i<count; i++)
           printf("backward relayy for ==%d\n", found_indices[i]);

   }else{
      printf("Relay not found in backward \n");
   }

}
```

Comment: You should post this on http://codereview.stackexchange.com/ instead.

Comment: You can indent it better..

Comment: @Joachim:Thank you, i will do it then..

Answer (score 0):

A more efficient way would be to transform `neighbor` into a bitmap. With your example, you could do it with 6 bytes (I am assuming possible values from 0 to 40):

00000001 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 01011000

Checking if a given number is in `neighbor` would just be a matter of checking if that bit is set, which is much more efficient than looping through an array.

Of course, this is a trivial example for which it would not make sense. But, if you had more values, then it would pay off.